# RingCt Is It Less Safe to Send the Whole Amount

Tags: ringct

## state 1

Initial positions:

```
A: 5.0032
B: 3.0000
C: 3.2000
```

...

## state 2

```
G:5.0032
H:2.0000
I:1.0000 
J:2.0000
K:1.2000
```

Let's assume

```
A -> G
B -> H,I
C -> J,K
```

I get you cannot tell for sure which inputs have been used to create the outputs (the same principle like a mixer). So `G` could have been created by sending `3` from `B` and `2.0032` from `C` or any other mix out of `A, B, C`

But isn't it more probable that an odd amount of the same size output/input is a full transaction?

Maybe I also have a misunderstanding what can be seen on the blockchain but there must be inputs/outputs in order to verify that the sum of inputs equals the sum of outputs in a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monero output amounts are encrypted. You cannot tell anything at all about the value of the inputs or outputs to a transaction (with the exception of freshly created coinbase outputs which have public amounts so that inflation can be tracked).

The validation that the sum of outputs+fee perfectly balances the sum of inputs is achieved using zero knowledge proofs.